# Using logical vectors and logical 2D array(MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, vector

I have two arrays of dimensions [1*10] using `randi`.

```
a1 = randi(100,1,10);
a2 = randi(100,1,10);
```

Now I need to create a third array (say `a3`) that contains the smallest number out of the two earlier arrays. 
I can do it using a `for` loop, but how can I solve it using a logical vector and no loops?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use logical vectors?

If not, `min([a1;a2])` will do the trick. It look at a matrix and finds the minimum along each column. So we if we build a matrix from your two vectors we're good to go.

Hacky way with logical vectors which you specified in your question for some reason:

```
smaller_ix = a1 < a2
v = zeros(1,10);
v(smaller_ix) = a1(smaller_ix)
v(~smaller_ix) = a2(~smaller_ix)
```

Comment: I don't think that's hacky at all.  But you are correct that `min` is the clearer, more efficient route.

Comment: Thanks Uri Merhav.

I used the min([a1;a2])  and it looks quite good except some of my values from new array are equal the previous arrays and not smaller than them. But it's a really good code.

I tried using this,

a1 = randi(100,1,10);
a2 = randi(100,1,10);

x = a1<=a2;
a3 = x.*a1;
y = find(~a3);
a3(y)=a2(y);

this seems to do the job but I wish there was a way to simplify things a little bit

Thanks.

Comment: Sujal, please flag it as answered if you feel this answered your question